# Scala - Problem using MapWrapper when upgrading from 2.7.7 to 2.8.1

Tags: scala

I have this piece of code I inherited that works well under Scala 2.7.7 (well, replacing the import to use jcl ). But when I try to use 2.8.1 I get this error:

> error: not enough arguments for constructor MapWrapper: (underlying: scala.collection.Map[String,String])collection.JavaConversions.MapWrapper[String,String].
> Unspecified value parameter underlying.
>
> Map.empty ++ new MapWrapper[String, String] {
>
> ```
>              ^
> ```

I have google high and low, tried different things but I can't find how to modify the code to work on scala 2.8.1

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.MapWrapper

object errorObj{
  def convertToStringMap(javaMap: Hashtable[String, String]) = {
    Map.empty ++ new MapWrapper[String, String] {
        def underlyinga = javaMap
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MapWrapper` is a class in Scala 2.8 (was a trait with abstract methods in 2.7). So, you don’t need to define the abstract method `underlying` anymore.

```
new MapWrapper[String, String](someMap)
```

Answer (score 2):

Better yet, just import `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` and let an implicit conversion turn the Java Map into a `MapWrapper` for you.